# Plone's edit fieldsets not appearing in tabs

Tags: plone

I upgraded one my Plone installations from 4.1.something to a 4.2.4 a while back. A weird thing then appeared: when editing any content, the fieldsets for that editing form all appeared one after another and not in their respective tabs.

Now when a user edits the content and hits "Save" they get a warning from the browser that they are about to leave the page. Paradoxically the user has to hit Leave Page because the changes *have* been changed. Clicking on one of the tab headings causes the changes to be lost and the edit session abandoned.

I don't think it's a theme thing - all the Plone instances on that server, each with a different theme - are exhibiting this problem.

Where would I start looking to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a javascript error.

The fieldset tabs are handled in pure JS; all but the first are hidden on page load.

Look in your browser console and see what is tripping up the JS and preventing the code from moving the fieldsets to tabs.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. There aren't any exceptions raised as the Edit page loads, and I've stepped through the load in form_tabbing.js and nothing jumps out at me. However when I hit Cancel in the form I get an exception on line 142: selected = ftabs.attr('value').replace(/^fieldsetlegend-/,'#fieldset-'); where ftabs is the ul.formTabs item.

Comment: The exception is related to the fact there are no tabs. The tabs are not created in the first place for some reason. It could be that the jQuery selector is not matching at all, but it is the initialisation you'll have to debug.

Comment: Is there any chance that you encountered a version conflict while upgrading, and ended up pinning Plone's jQuery support to a different version than the default? That, by my experience, is the most common cause of this class of problem.

Comment: Thanks Steve. It might have happened - I don't recall a problem. I have the addon "Plone JQuery Integration 1.4.4" selected in the add-ons setup - not sure if that is the right version or not.

Comment: Aarrgh! I had the add-on " jQuery UI 1.10.0.1" enabled - for a reason I cannot recall, another add-on must have need it. By de-activating it and re-activating it the problem seems to be solved! Everything is in the tabs again, and "Save" doesn't confuse the users. Thanks for your suggestions which pointed me in the right direction.